# Singularity of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z\sin(\frac{1}{z+1})$. There is a singularity at $z=-1$. Is it essential, removable or a pole?
I tried to compute a couple of limits and stuff, but to no avail.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z$ is analytic at $-1$, the singularity type is the same as for $\sin\frac1z$ at $z=0$. This takes on arbitrary values if $z\approx0$, i.e. it is an essential singularity. (or just note that not even $\lim_{t\to0}\sin\frac1t$ exists in the reals)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was essential, I have just realised that setting $w=1+z$ makes everything easier.